# What mysql code do I need to use? to find all ids made between date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to work out the amount of ids between two dates basically I want to find out how many users I have gotten today so im not sure what I need for it really :/

I have a column call date which has the users date of registration 
And I have the ID column of course which will help

Please help

Comment: Use the SQL keyword `BETWEEN` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`BETWEEN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between). For example:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total_users
FROM
    users
WHERE
    date_of_registration BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND INTERVAL CURRENT_DATE - 1 WEEK
```

Comment: What should I replace total users with? ID? and ID for users too? and replace date registered with my date column?

Comment: Sure. My example just shows you how it works in general. You can definitely customize it to suit your needs.

Comment: sorry im a bit of a noob for the FROM bit do I put the table it is usigng?

Comment: Yes. Change `users` to the name of the table you want to use.

Comment: and total users becomes ID right? I replace date of reg to date and it becomes orange and wont errors

Comment: Actually no. Since you just want a count of users you don't need to change that (unless you prefer a different alias to the count you get as a result of the query).

Comment: What is the name of your column that the registration date is stored in?

Comment: @Jeremyc, since you described yourself as a noob, you might want to invest some time into learning the fundamentals rather than stumbling about as you try to do stuff.  I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Im trying SELECT COUNT( * ) AS username
FROM members
WHERE DATE
BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE
AND INTERVAL CURRENT_DATE -1 WEEK but its not working :S the date of reg is called date

Comment: also the date is formatted like 14-08-2012 in my column @JohnConde

Comment: error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 @JohnConde

Comment: Try putting ticks ` around "DATE"

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query. If you want to go so far as to set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that may help to figure it out.

Comment: it fails on that too :S. @JohnConde

Comment: But then I can play with it, too!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    t1
WHERE
    DATE(`date`) = CURDATE()
```

The `DATE()` call is onlyi necessary of `date` is a timestamp.